# PHP - Order slides evenly over 7 days between elements (scalable)

Tags: php

Currently I display 4 slides over a 7 day period as shown in the code below. I do it this way so then each item gets a fair turn at being slide one, two, three etc etc. Can anyone see a better way to do this? Currently if i wish to add a new slide i have to rearrange the order of every variable which is not ideal.

```
<?php
$varOne = "<li>varOne item</li>";
$varTwo = "<li>varTwo item</li>";
$varThree = "<li>varThree item</li>";
$varFour = "<li>varFour item</li>";

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$day = date("D");

if($day == "Mon"){
    $items = compact('varOne','varTwo','varThree','varFour');

} elseif($day == "Tue"){
    $items = compact('varFour','varOne','varTwo','varThree');

} elseif($day == "Wed"){
    $items = compact('varThree','varFour','varOne','varTwo');

} elseif($day == "Thur"){
    $items = compact('varTwo','varThree','varFour','varOne');

} elseif($day == "Fri"){
    $items = compact('varOne','varTwo','varThree','varFour');

} elseif($day == "Sat"){
    $items = compact('varFour','varOne','varTwo','varThree');

} elseif($day == "Sun"){
    $items = compact('varThree','varFour','varOne','varTwo');

}

echo "<ul>";
foreach($items as $item){
    echo $item;
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: Do you know a max-number of slide that could be available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fill the `$items` array and you're done:

```
$items = array(
    "<li>varOne item</li>",
    "<li>varTwo item</li>",
    "<li>varThree item</li>",
    "<li>varFour item</li>",
);

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$start = date('N') - 1; // not quite right but working    

$infinite = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($items));
$limit = new LimitIterator($infinite, $start, count($items));

echo "<ul>";
foreach($limit as $item){
    echo $item;
}
echo "</ul>";
```

**Explanation:**

It works with the combination of [InfiniteIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.infiniteiterator.php) and [LimitIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php).

> The InfiniteIterator allows one to infinitely iterate over an iterator without having to manually rewind the iterator upon reaching its end.

And the `LimitIterator`:

> The LimitIterator class allows iteration over a limited subset of items in an Iterator.

Just look at and try the examples on the pages I posted. There are more iterators in the SPL (Standard PHP Library). They are very helpful.

[SPL Iterators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php)

`date('N')` returns the integers `1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)`. So I just substracted by one because the `LimitIterator` `$offset` (`$start`) is zero based. I've commented with `not quite right but working` because you use another rotation. (tuesday should beginn with varFour and not varTwo) Just try to change the `$start` variable. I leave that up to you as a challenge. ;)

By the way it's worth to look at the other things the SPL offers. There are very cool Datastructures, Exceptions and Interfaces etc. that you can use and don't have to reinvent the wheel.

[Standard PHP Library (SPL)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php)

Comment: Would this achieve the different order per day over a 7 day period ensuring each item gets a fair order( within reason given the odd number)?

Comment: yes, it will give the same output. just a little more dynamicly.

Comment: Thanks, i tried researching your answer so then i could understand how it works. Could you briefly explain what is happening if that's ok? Many thanks, marked as correct.

Comment: Excellent answer on all levels +1

Answer (score 0):

if you knew that, for example, 7 was the max amount of slide allowed

```
$varOne = "<li>varOne item</li>";
$varTwo = "<li>varTwo item</li>";
$varThree = "<li>varThree item</li>";
$varFour = "<li>varFour item</li>";
$varFive = ""; // populate if and when required
$varSix = ""; // populate if and when required
$varSeven = ""; // populate if and when required

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$day = date("D");

if($day == "Mon"){
    $items = compact('varOne','varTwo','varThree','varFour','varFive','varSix','varSeven');

} elseif($day == "Tue"){
    $items = compact('varSeven','varFour','varOne','varTwo','varThree','varFive','varSix');

} elseif($day == "Wed"){
    $items = compact('varSix','varSeven','varThree','varFour','varOne','varTwo','varFive');

} elseif($day == "Thur"){
    $items = compact('varFive','varSix','varSeven','varTwo','varThree','varFour','varOne');

} elseif($day == "Fri"){
    $items = compact('varOne','varTwo','varThree','varFour','varFive','varSix','varSeven');

} elseif($day == "Sat"){
    $items = compact('varFour','varOne','varFive','varSix','varSeven','varTwo','varThree');

} elseif($day == "Sun"){
    $items = compact('varThree','varFour','varFive','varSix','varSeven','varOne','varTwo');

}

echo "<ul>";
foreach($items as $item){
    if($item !=""){
        echo $item;
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```